# Is it possible to force an SFX to run in silent mode that wasn't otherwise created as such

Tags: winrar

I have a third party SFX I want to deploy, but it runs in graphical mode at the moment.  I have tried various command line parameters, to see if I can invoke it in silent mode or CLI mode, but it does't seem to want to play.

Answer (score 1):

Oh well.

```
$ xxd sfx.exe | head
0000000: 4d5a 9000 0300 0000 0400 0000 ffff 0000  MZ..............
0000010: b800 0000 0000 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000  ........@.......
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 8000 0000  ................
0000040: 0e1f ba0e 00b4 09cd 21b8 014c cd21 5468  ........!..L.!Th
0000050: 6973 2070 726f 6772 616d 2063 616e 6e6f  is program canno
0000060: 7420 6265 2072 756e 2069 6e20 444f 5320  t be run in DOS 
0000070: 6d6f 6465 2e0d 0d0a 2400 0000 0000 0000  mode....$.......
0000080: 5045 0000 4c01 0700 55cd cc33 0000 0000  PE..L...U..3....
0000090: 0000 0000 e000 0e01 0b01 0414 003a 0000  .............:..
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Run SFX .exe for get  files source
2. Create a new SFX with your options desired
3. Happy codding Easy!